# Download a file to StreamingAssets folder using Unity and c#

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine, download

Im trying to download a txt file at runtime in Streaming Assets folder in a Windows based game using Unity 5.6.1 and c#. I have found some data in the manual and some examples here and there and made this although its not working, I hope you can point me in the right direction. Thanks beforehand

The current test text file is called cont.txt and can be found in my site so the url is correct and tested

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;
public class webreq : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetText("cont")); 
    }

    IEnumerator GetText(string file_name)
    {
        string url = "http://www.mordazah.com/" + file_name + ".txt";
        Debug.Log(url);
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            yield return www.Send();

            string savePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}.txt", Application.streamingAssetsPath, file_name);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(savePath, www.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I forgot to mention there is no error just its not doing what is suppossed to do, in this case download the txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting errors because the directory and path do not exist. `File.WriteAllText` will create the file, or overwrite if exists, but will not create your directory.

You need to use `Directory.CreateDirectory(String);`

> Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path
>   unless they already exist.

Also use [SendWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.SendWebRequest.html) as `Send` is depcrecated.

See the comments inline below:

```
void Start () {
    StartCoroutine (GetRequest ("cont.txt"));
}

IEnumerator GetRequest (string file_name) {
    // use concat with joining strings
    var uri = string.Concat ("http://www.mordazah.com/", file_name);
    using (var webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get (uri)) {
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest (); // send is deprecated

        if (webRequest.isNetworkError) {
            Debug.LogError (webRequest.error);
        }
        else {
            // ensure you have this directory - will not throw if it exists
            Directory.CreateDirectory (Application.streamingAssetsPath);

            // create the appropriate path to save to using Path.Combine()
            var savePath = Path.Combine (Application.streamingAssetsPath, file_name);

            File.WriteAllText (savePath, webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes that solved it, I have used Streaming assets folder in other project but in that one I was reading from it so I made it manually and somehow I thought it would be created if needed automatically, of course that never happened, made one but for some reason it was not being recognized, then using your suggested command it worked fine =). The SendWebRequest seems to be not available in my version or its not recognized a valid command in my 5.6.1, I know I should update but I just put a game on sale in Steam and I dont know if I would make any change in it